# Prove the following property about natural integral

Tags: integration, formal-proof, divergent-integrals

Natural integral is the distinguished antiderivative of a function that can be understood as an analytic continuation of consecutive derivatives of a function towards $-1$th order. It is defined as

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$

or

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{- i \omega x}\omega^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega = i\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(x^{-1} \mathcal{F}(f(x))\right)$$

I would like to see the proof of the conjectured property of natural integral that

$$\int_{-\infty}^0f(x)dx-\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx=2f^{(-1)}(0
)$$

Where if the integrals diverge they are taken as their regularized values and if $f^{(-1)}(x)$ has a pole at zero it should be taken as Cauchy principal value.

In other words, I wonder whether the following definition of natural intergal is equivalent to the previous ones:

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \, dt+\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{-\infty }^0 f(t) \, dt-\int_0^{\infty } f(t) \, dt\right)$$

Comment: Cauchy, please!

Comment: is $\binom{-1}m$ just $(-1)^m$?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov fixed this